# PHP preg_match_all on variable field positions with named groups

Tags: php, regex

I have a situation where I need to match on a web server log entry where the location of the named groups is dynamic within the log.

For example:

Log 1: user=mike&time=now&sport=hockey&something

Log 2: time=now&sport=hockey&user=mike&something

Log 3: sport=hockey&time=now&user=mike&something

For the purpose of my application, I need to used named groups. All online regex testers show that the below method works, but the array returned in PHP is somewhat of a mess.

Here is my regex:

```
(?J)((time=(?<time>.*?))|(name=(?<name>.*?))|(sport=(?<sport>.*?)))\&((time=(?<time>.*?))|(name=(?<name>.*?))|(sport=(?<sport>.*?)))\&(?J)((time=(?<time>.*?))|(name=(?<name>.*?))|(sport=(?<sport>.*?)))\&something*
```

The array returned by php is something of a mess:

```
array(25) {
  [0]=>
  string(41) "name=mike&time=now&sport=hockey&something"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "name=mike"
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["time"]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(9) "name=mike"
  ["name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  [5]=>
  string(4) "mike"
  [6]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["sport"]=>
  string(6) "hockey"
  [7]=>
  string(0) ""
  [8]=>
  string(8) "time=now"
  [9]=>
  string(8) "time=now"
  [10]=>
  string(3) "now"
  [11]=>
  string(0) ""
  [12]=>
  string(0) ""
  [13]=>
  string(0) ""
  [14]=>
  string(0) ""
  [15]=>
  string(12) "sport=hockey"
  [16]=>
  string(0) ""
  [17]=>
  string(0) ""
  [18]=>
  string(0) ""
  [19]=>
  string(0) ""
  [20]=>
  string(12) "sport=hockey"
  [21]=>
  string(6) "hockey"
}
```

Only the last field gets matched in a proper named group. I've tried numerous renditions of the regex, but always the same results are yielded: a messed-up array.

Any assistance or pointers is appreciated.

Comment: Honestly? I think your regex is messed up. I would write a general regex and then use `parse_str()` to get those values.

Comment: Honestly. I have a solution to use PHP to extract the values in this case. the problem is that this is part of another function that handles other, more simple log file entries from various sources, and I am trying to find a regex to return the correct values without having to add an exception to this scenario. In theory, my regex works, but the array returned by PHP is not desirable.

Comment: Here's a quick pure regex solution https://regex101.com/r/fN2eN6/2 , in php you would just need the sub arrays time, name and sport. I was writing a php solution but then I read your comment... I will post it anyway: https://eval.in/private/c0bcd3cd8c5e41 make sure to check out https://regex101.com/r/fN2eN6/3 . Going to sleep, hope I helped you out. Who knows? I might post this as an answer tomorrow, or not... :)

Comment: works perfectly. Im not familiar enough with lookaheads, but I will def. spend some time looking into it. I was able to wrap your example inside of the full regex I created and it works perfectly. Please post your solution as an answer. Anyone looking to parse Microsoft ActiveSync logs with PCRE will be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to HamZa, the solution ended up being positive lookaheads instead of a conditional match. The following regex properly matches the conditions regardless of their position.

```
(?=\S*time=(?<time>[^=&]*))(?=\S*user=(?<name>[^=&]*))(?=\S*sport=(?<sport>[^=&]*))\S+?&something
```